# Ruby on Rails - Routing - Appropriate situations to use a namespace over a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I have a few navigation items that are dropdown menus. The only constraint I have is that each link in a dropdown menu should have its url path prefixed with the menu name that it belong to. For example:

```
http://example.com/dropdown1/page1
http://example.com/dropdown1/page2
http://example.com/dropdown1/page3
http://example.com/dropdown2/page4
http://example.com/dropdown3/page5
http://example.com/dropdown3/page6
```

I understand that I have two options when creating the routes for these pages.

1. Use a scope. Only the url path is scoped / prefixed.
2. Use a namespace. In addition to the url being scoped / prefixed, the controllers, views, models, and path helpers will be namespaced as well.

The pages in each dropdown house different independent features, but each feature in the dropdown shares the same category. Does it make more sense to namespace these features or to just scope them?

Answer (score 0):

If your *only constraint is that each link in a dropdown menu must have its url path prefixed with the menu name that it belongs to*, then my suggestion is to just **scope the routes** for those dropdown paths.

Namespacing provides a greater degree of separation out of the box, and is more useful for scenarios like having an admin section, or an API layer, where the same resources would behave differently depending on their namespace.

Scoping gives you a bit more control, allowing you to specify what should be namespaced - in this case if only the routes are different, then you can have something like:

```
scope 'dropdown1' do
  # routing here
end
```

The Rails guides does a good job explaining the [usage of namespacing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing):

> Most commonly, you might group a number of administrative controllers under an Admin:: namespace. You would place these controllers under the app/controllers/admin directory, and you can group them together in your router.